# Fixing the position of apply button in Multi-Select Checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have designed multi-select checkbox by using some code snippets.

However, I don't want user to scroll down to the list to select the apply button.

In the Following Snapshot, There is no apply button unless user scroll bottom of the list.

What I am trying to achieve is to show the scroll bar between Select Measure and Apply Button.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/harsha547/x27181u6/)

[image: Snapshot]

```js
 var expanded = false;

        function showCheckboxes() {
            var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
            if (!expanded) {
                checkboxes.style.display = "block";
                expanded = true;
            } else {
                checkboxes.style.display = "none";
                expanded = false;
            }
        }

        function closebox() {
            var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
            $(checkboxes).delay(5000).fadeIn();
            checkboxes.style.display = "none";
        }

        function sleep(miliseconds) {
            var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
            while (currentTime + miliseconds >= new Date().getTime()) {}
        }

        function getvalues() {
            var str = '';
            var checks = document.getElementsByClassName('checks');
            for (i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
                if (checks[i].checked === true) {
                    str += checks[i].value + " ";
                }
            }
            alert(str);
        }

        function getvalue() {
            var str = '';
            var checks = document.getElementsByClassName('checks');
            alert(checks[0].checked);
        }
```

```css
.multiselect {
            width: 180px;
        }

        .selectBox {
            /* position: relative; */
            position: relative
        }

        .selectBox select {
            width: 100%;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .overSelect {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
        }

        #checkboxes {
            display: none;
            line-height: 0px;
            height: 100px;
            padding: 0px;
            border: 1px #dadada solid;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }

        #checkboxes::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 6px;
        }

        #checkboxes::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            background-color: grey;
            outline: 1px solid slategrey;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }

        select {
            background-color: #e6e6e6;
            border: thin solid #e6e6e6;
            border-radius: 4px;
            display: inline-block;
            font: inherit;
            line-height: 1em;
            padding: 0.5em 3.5em 0.5em 1em;
            margin: 0;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            -moz-appearance: none;
            width: 100%;
            cursor: pointer;
            outline: 0;
            color: #7b7b7b;
        }

        .selectBox:after {
            content: "\f13a";
            font-family: "FontAwesome";
            padding: 10px 0px 10px 2px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 10px;
            top: 0;
            color: #7b7b7b;
            font-size: 15px;
            z-index: 1;
            text-align: center;
            width: 10%;
            height: 100%;
            pointer-events: none;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        label {
            cursor: pointer;
            color: #666;
            display: block;
            margin: 0px 4px 2px -29px;
            padding: 3px;
        }

        input[type="checkbox"] {
            display: none;
        }

        input[type="checkbox"]+.label-text:before {
            content: "\f096";
            font-family: "FontAwesome";
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
            font-variant: normal;
            text-transform: none;
            line-height: 1;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            width: 1em;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: 5px;
        }

        input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.label-text:before {
            content: "\f14a";
            color: #06a3e9;
        }

        input[type="checkbox"]:disabled+.label-text {
            color: #aaa;
        }

        input[type="checkbox"]:disabled+.label-text:before {
            content: "\f0c8";
            color: #ccc;
        }

        .submit {
            background: #ff8080;
            color: #008080;
            padding: 10px 5px 5px;
            border: 0;
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 14px;
            cursor: pointer;
            text-align: center;
        }

        ul {
            padding: 0px 0px 2px 34px;
        }

        li {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0px;
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
        <div class="multiselect">
            <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
                <select class="round">
                 <option>Select Measure</option>
                </select>
                <div class="overSelect"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="checkboxes">
                <ul>
                    <li> <label>   <input type="checkbox" name="" class="checks" value="1" onchange="closebox()"><span class="label-text">Item One</span></label></li>
                    <li><label>   <input type="checkbox" name="" class="checks" value="2"><span class="label-text">Item Two</span></label></li>
                    <li><label>   <input type="checkbox" name="" class="checks" value="3" ><span class="label-text">Item Three</span></label></li>
                    <li><label>   <input type="checkbox" name="" class="checks" value="4" ><span class="label-text">Item Four</span></label></li>
                    <li> <label>   <input type="checkbox" name="" class="checks" value="5" ><span class="label-text">Item Five</span></label></li>
                    <li><label>   <input type="checkbox" name="" class="checks" value="6" ><span class="label-text">Item Six</span></label></li>
                </ul>
                <label> <input type="submit" class="submit round" value="APPLY"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <button onclick="getvalues()"> Get Values </button>
```

/

Comment: Add the link to the relevant jsfiddle

Comment: fiddle is empty

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/harsha547/x27181u6/

Comment: Suggest me, If there is any help  that I could provide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the `label` out of the checkboxes, so when you scroll - you will scroll only the checkboxes:

```js
var expanded = false;

        function showCheckboxes() {
            var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes-container");
            if (!expanded) {
                checkboxes.style.display = "block";
                expanded = true;
            } else {
                checkboxes.style.display = "none";
                expanded = false;
            }
        }

        function closebox() {
            var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes-container");
            $(checkboxes).delay(5000).fadeIn();
            checkboxes.style.display = "none";
        }

        function sleep(miliseconds) {
            var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
            while (currentTime + miliseconds >= new Date().getTime()) {}
        }

        function getvalues() {
            var str = '';
            var checks = document.getElementsByClassName('checks');
            for (i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
                if (checks[i].checked === true) {
                    str += checks[i].value + " ";
                }
            }
            alert(str);
        }

        function getvalue() {
            var str = '';
            var checks = document.getElementsByClassName('checks');
            alert(checks[0].checked);
        }
```

```css
.multiselect {
  width: 180px;
}

.selectBox {
  /* position: relative; */
  position: relative
}

.selectBox select {
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.overSelect {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
#checkboxes-container {
  display: none;
  height: 120px;
}
#checkboxes {
  line-height: 0px;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px #dadada solid;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#checkboxes::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 6px;
}

#checkboxes::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: grey;
  outline: 1px solid slategrey;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

select {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  border: thin solid #e6e6e6;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  font: inherit;
  line-height: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em 3.5em 0.5em 1em;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0;
  color: #7b7b7b;
}

.selectBox:after {
  content: "\f13a";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 2px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 0;
  color: #7b7b7b;
  font-size: 15px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #666;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px 4px 2px -29px;
  padding: 3px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]+.label-text:before {
  content: "\f096";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  width: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.label-text:before {
  content: "\f14a";
  color: #06a3e9;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:disabled+.label-text {
  color: #aaa;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:disabled+.label-text:before {
  content: "\f0c8";
  color: #ccc;
}

.submit {
  background: #ff8080;
  color: #008080;
  padding: 10px 5px 5px;
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  padding: 0px 0px 2px 34px;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<form>
        <div class="multiselect">
            <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
                <select class="round">
                 <option>Select Measure</option>
                </select>
                <div class="overSelect"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="checkboxes-container">
              <div id="checkboxes">
                <ul>
                    <li> <label>   <input type="checkbox" name="" class="checks" value="1" onchange="closebox()"><span class="label-text">Item One</span></label></li>
                    <li><label>   <input type="checkbox" name="" class="checks" value="2"><span class="label-text">Item Two</span></label></li>
                    <li><label>   <input type="checkbox" name="" class="checks" value="3" ><span class="label-text">Item Three</span></label></li>
                    <li><label>   <input type="checkbox" name="" class="checks" value="4" ><span class="label-text">Item Four</span></label></li>
                    <li> <label>   <input type="checkbox" name="" class="checks" value="5" ><span class="label-text">Item Five</span></label></li>
                    <li><label>   <input type="checkbox" name="" class="checks" value="6" ><span class="label-text">Item Six</span></label></li>
                </ul>
              </div> 
              <label> <input type="submit" class="submit round" value="APPLY"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <button onclick="getvalues()"> Get Values </button>
```

Comment: I hope, If I add border and alignment to Apply div , It won't like separate from the filter

Comment: You hope what? I gave an example with the exact code that works... did you check it?

Comment: Sure, I will do it